# Checking a series of numbers for consistency

Tags: objective-c, ios, math, nsarray, logic

I maintain an array of integers.  It is important that at all times the integers in this array are in sequence from 0.  For example, if there are 5 integers in the array, their values must be 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 (though in any order).

I would like to design a simple, efficient method that checks this.  It will return true if the array contains all positive integers in sequence from 0 to array.count - 1.

I would love to hear some different ideas for handling this!

Comment: If you need to be *sure*, you can't do any better than going through each element in the array and checking. So just count from 0 to the array's length minus one, and check that what's in position `i` of the array is in fact the value `i`. (The only "optimization" there is is to return false whenever you encounter an element that's not what it should be, instead of continuing the count). Edit: Oh and, Mathias makes a good point: What's the point of keeping this array anyway? You know well how to compute every natural number below `n`, so why keep them all stored?

Comment: What do you use the array for? Wouldn't it be easier to maintain the upper bound of the array, and iterate over integers?

Comment: I use the array to populate a tableview.  The numbers are sort orders.  I drop items in and out of sections in different ways, and just want a method that ensures I am setting the sort orders correctly, so that after I move an item in/out of a section, there are no gaps etc.  I will post what I am currently doing - I think it fits with your suggestions.  Was just wondering if there was a craftier way (I was looking at summing the numbers and comparing to a fibonacci sequence for example - probably wouldn't be as efficient but might be fun).

Comment: @gspr - I don't care much about the order, so I am using containsObject rather than objectForIndex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't too different from your itemsSequencedCorrectlyInSet: method, but it uses a mutable index set which will be faster than doing -[NSSet containsObject:]. Probably not an issue until you've got thousands of table rows. Anyway, the key insight here is that the Pigeonhole Principle says if you've got N integers less than N and none is duplicated, then you have each of 0...N-1 exactly once.

```
-(BOOL)listIsValid:(NSArray*)list
{
    NSMutableIndexSet* seen = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSet];

    for ( NSNumber* number in list )
    {
        NSUInteger n = [number unsignedIntegerValue];

        if ( n >= [array count] || [seen containsIndex:n] )
            return NO;

        [seen addIndex:n];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Since I mentioned 'efficient' in my question, and this seems the most pragmatic, I'll go with it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Or, given the integers `[0..N-1]` if you raise 2 to the power of each in turn the sum will be `-1+2^N`.  This is not a property that any other set of N integers has.

I offer this as an alternative, making no claim about suitability, performance or efficiency, and I recognise that there will be problems as N gets large.

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you want to test is if your array is a permutation of `[0...n-1]`. There are easy algorithms for this that are `O(n)` in both time and memory. See for example this [PDF file](http://personal.denison.edu/~havill/algorithmics/algs/permutation.pdf).

Sometimes I use a very simple check that is `O(n)` in time and `O(1)` in memory. It can in theory return false positives, but it is a good way to find most mistakes. It is based on the following facts:

```
0 + 1 + 2 + ... + n-1 == n * (n-1) / 2
0 + 1² + 2² + ... + (n-1)² == n * (n-1) * (2 * n - 1) / 6
```

I don't know objective-c, but the code would look like this in C#:

```
bool IsPermutation(int[] array)
{
    long length = array.Length;
    long total1 = 0;
    long total2 = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i<length; i++)
    {
        total1 += array[i];
        total2 += (long)array[i] * array[i];
    }

    return 
       2 * total1 == length * (length - 1) &&
       6 * total2 == length * (length - 1) * (2 * length - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my current implementation (testSet is a set of NSNumbers) -

```
    - (BOOL)itemsSequencedCorrectlyInSet:(NSSet *)testSet{
        for (NSInteger i = 0; i < testSet.count; i++) {
               if (![testSet containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:i]]) {
                    return NO;
               }
         }

         return YES;
    }
```